# Incoming $_GET array is empty on my nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

i have nginx configured like this:

```
server {
    listen   80; 
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;
    root /www/repos/havi/$subdomain;
    index index.php;

    server_name domain.com *.domain.com;

set $subdomain "www";

    location / 
    {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }


    location ~ /\.ht 
    {
            deny all;
    }

if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-\.]+)\.domain.com$) 
{
    set $subdomain $1;
}
```

}

And i have no idea why the $_GET array (php) always empty if i tried to set it through the link like:

```
http://domain.com/action?name=John&age=15
```

There is empty array coming each time.
On my local machine with local Apache server the same code works right.

Help. please ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` to include the $_GET parameters when you pass the user off to index.php